# Looking for a Book about Alleged Suicide(s) Which Are Actually Murders

Tags: identification-request

I read this book sometime between 2009 and 2012. It was a mystery novel, and the POV character (don't remember if it was third or first person) was a schoolgirl, who is probably in high school.

She discovers a body, I think in the dead person's bedroom, and calls the police, and the policewoman warns her not to touch anything. When the policewoman arrives, she explains that if the girl had touched anything, she might have ruined evidence like fingerprints. The girl points out something unusual about the crime scene, an alleged suicide - I think it was that the person had supposedly shot themself in the head with a gun, but the gun was in the wrong hand (the person was left-handed instead of right-handed).

Later in the book, a classmate of the girl asks her to copy some lines from a book for her, and she realizes that the lines he asked her to copy are very similar to a suicide note from a previous case. She realizes that the boy is the culprit - he asked students from their school to copy lines for him, and then killed those students, making the copied lines out to be their suicide notes.

Since I read this in middle school, this is probably a book intended for middle or high school students. I don't think it was a very long book. Anyone know what this is?

Update: I got this book from my school library. I believe it was paperback. I don't remember anything about the cover, and it definitely wasn't a historical novel, but I'm not sure it was set during the time I read it; I don't recall much use (if any) of modern tech in the story.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please see the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] your question to add more information. For example, was the story in English? Do you remember anything about the cover? Do you remember the story being older ("classic"?) or relatively newer at the time? Any detail may help identify the novel

Comment: I think this is a common motif in stories and you don't provide a lot to go on. There are some examples of stories where it looks like suicide but isn't on [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverSuicide) so you could see if any match (the website covers all forms of media not just TV).